# Jquery document ready not firing in 2+, document load not firing

Tags: jquery

I cannot get a document.load event to fire, and in jQuery 2+, I can't get the document.ready to fire either.  How can I make document.ready work in jQuery 2+, and how can I make .load work?
Thanks!

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2x7SP/2/

```
    (function($) {
$(document).ready(documentReadyFunction);
$(document).load(afterPageLoad);

function documentReadyFunction() {
  $('#readytext').val('READY');
}

function afterPageLoad () {
  //alert ('loaded');
  $('#loadtext').val('LOAD');
}

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? the document doesn't have a load event (but the window does! http://jsfiddle.net/2x7SP/3/) jquery 2.x doesn't support IE6-8

Comment: There is $(window).load not $(document).load .... try `$(window).on('load', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load` event is fired by the window, not by document. By changing it, it works fine.

Code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(documentReadyFunction);
    $(window).load(afterPageLoad);

    function documentReadyFunction() {
        $('#readytext').val('READY');
    }

    function afterPageLoad() {
        //alert ('loaded');
        $('#loadtext').val('LOAD');
    }

})(jQuery);
```

jQuery 2 dropped the support to old IE versions http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/ :

> As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6,
>   7, and 8 browsers. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in
>   JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility
>   often causes problems of its own. But don’t worry, the jQuery team
>   still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8. You can (and
>   should) continue to use jQuery 1.9 (and the upcoming 1.10) on web
>   sites that need to accommodate older browsers.

If you need to support IE<9 you have to switch to jQuery 1.x.

Ref: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7CpF7/

Comment: Looks like I haven't updated IE since version 9.  This is working as long as I don't use IE9 and jQuery 2.0.2.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle jquery 2+ DOES work in IE9, if you're running in IE9 standards mode.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification - I was really banging my head on the most simple thing.  For now I don't want to drop IE 8-9.

Comment: @Kevin B - For IE standards mode, is anything required besides putting <!doctype html> on line 1?

Comment: @JenniferMichelle nope. note however that depending on your settings, intranet sites/applications may default to quirks mode or old browser mode.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. There is no such thing as `document.load`. The `load` event is only fired by elements associated with a URL, such as an image or an iframe, or the `window` object, which is probably the one you want to use.
2. In the fiddle, jQuery is wrapped in the `load` handler, which means that `load` has already fired.

The code is fine as long as you replace `document.load` with `window.load`:

```
$(window).load(afterPageLoad);
```

And don't wrap the jQuery in the load event. Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNUv2/

Comment: Thanks Nicklas, My issue appears to be jQuery 2.0.2 or 2.0.3 with IE9.  I will revert to older jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function documentReadyFunction() {
    $('#readytext').val('READY');
}

function afterPageLoad() {
    $('#loadtext').val('LOAD');
}

$(document).ready(documentReadyFunction);
$(window).load(afterPageLoad);
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2x7SP/5/)